# Is my synthesizer too quiet?

Tags: sound, synthesizer, line-level, quiet

My synthesizer (Yamaha mx88) is plugged into the back (which has no gain controls) of my audio interface (Focusrite Scarlett 4i4) and that is plugged into my laptop (MacBook pro) running Focusrite control and Ableton live. The signal reads around -36db. Is this normal? Why is the signal so low?

Comment: can you provide more info: what settings on synth, what kind of interface, what input and gain are you using on it. etc

Comment: @RoryAlsop yes I'll do an edit

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your signal is too low.

This can come, e.g. from impedance mismatch (i.e. output and input aer a bad couple).

Sometimes using the headphone output helps.

A preamp inserted might help. However, e.g. with impedance mismatch, you may experience more noise.